# Return value from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, last.fm

I'm trying to return the value [name] from the following array (last.fm)

```
Array
(
[totalResults] => 9771
[startIndex] => 0
[itemsPerPage] => 1
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Beyoncé
                [mbid] => 183105b5-3e68-4748-9086-2c1c11bf7a3d
                [url] => http://www.last.fm/music/Beyonc%C3%A9
                [streamable] => 1
                [image] => Array
                    (
                        [small] => 
                        [large] => http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/95313353.png
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I tried

```
echo $results['0'][0];
```

Where $results is the array variable, but not worked. I have no clue. Can you help me to retune the value from [name] (in this case Beyonce) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$results[0]['name']`?

Comment: [The manual is your friend](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access each nested result by it's key. In this case "results" > 0 (numeric index) > "name":

```
echo $results['results'][0]['name'];
```